# call function from element with parameters

Tags: cakephp, controller, element

I'm calling from my element to a function of a controller. I sent the parameters you need. The problem I have is that in my element such value is TRUE, but when the driver arrives arrives FALSE, I do not understand why this happens. Clean temporary folder and cache, I closed and opened files again but nothing. I get not identify what the problem is why I come to you. I hope you can help me.

Call to element, The parameter I need is `'web'`

```
echo $this->element(
    'atributo_element', 
    array(
        'data'=>$atributo, 
        'eventID'=>$eventID, 
        'format'=>'simple',
        'evento'=>$evento, 
        'input_value'=>$input_value, 
        'setup'=>$setup, 
        'web' => true
    )
);
```

element.ctp

```
print_r($web); // ====> 1
$this->requestAction(
    array(
        'controller'=>'tickets',
        'action'=>'listado',
        'admin'=>false
    ),
    array($eventID, $inscID, $web)
);
```

Controller

```
public function listado($evento_id = null, $inscripcion_id = null, $web = false) {
    print_r($web); //=====> false 
    $tickets = $this->Ticket->getTicketsActivos($evento_id, $web);
}
```

**EDIT**

Trying to find the error, something strange probe

```
echo $this->Html->link(array('controller'=>'tickets', 'action'=>'listado', 'admin'=>false),
                                         array($eventID,$inscID, $web));
```

This actually prints the value of web as in 1, but function never receives it as 1 is too weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting up the URL for the `requestAction()` incorrectly. You need to pass all the routing parameters in the second array with the `'pass'` index:-

```
$this->requestAction(
    array(
        'controller' => 'tickets',
        'action' => 'listado',
        'admin' => false,
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array(
            $eventID,
            $inscID, 
            $web
        )
    )
);
```

What you're doing is calling your controller action as `listado()` without any parameters so essentially `listado(null, null, false)`.

Your example of using `$this->Html->link()` is wrong because the passed parameters need to be defined in the same array as the other router parameters with the first parameter as the name of the link:-

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'link',
    array(
        'controller' => 'tickets', 
        'action' => 'listado', 
        'admin' => false,
        $eventID,
        $inscID, 
        $web
    )
);
```

It's worth noting that `requestAction()` can lead to poor performance and is best avoided if possible.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer !. Try to do as you indicate but still have the same problem. Regarding the requestAction, that would be the best way to call the function?

Comment: `requestAction` creates an extra server request which is why it's not recommended (you want to keep requests to a minimum). Ideally you should be setting everything up for your view in your controller before rendering it.

Comment: Are you sure `$web` is `true`?

Comment: If I print everywhere and everywhere is true (or 1) but the controller comes to false, it seems extremely rare this had never happened to me: S

Comment: I've just updated my answer, ignore what I originally said. I forgot that with `requestAction` you have to use the `pass` index for the second array as it bypasses the normal `Router::url()`.

Comment: After various tests come to the conclusion that url does not work for me send the Boolean data. Probe data with strings and everything worked well but it was not what I expected. Let's ignore the requestAction and change code to make it much better. Thanks for your help!